# Diff tool that compares methods directly (ignores reordering)?

Tags: java, merge, diff

Say I have this source code file that has been changed:

Before:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("bar");
    }

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}
```

After:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("foobar");
    }

    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("bar");
    }
}
```

Most diff tools will report that the old method foo was deleted, and a new method foo was added, when in reality it was simply moved to a different location and updated. Are there any diff tools which can intelligently recognize that the method was moved and compare the differing sections of the method, instead of reporting that an entire section of code was deleted or added?

Comment: AFAIK, [semantic diff](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/SemanticDiff.html) is the only somewhat commonly accepted term for what you're asking about.  There's at least one commercial product that claims to do it, which you can easily find by searching that term, but I know nothing about it.

Comment: I've used p4 diff in the past and I recall it would show that a code block had moved (it is still a diff)

Comment: I did a quick search and found this: https://github.com/le-moulin-studio/java-semantic-diff  Perhaps you will find it useful.